# Investigating nested Divs in Ruby and Page-Object

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I am trying to print out the text in the nested divs.
I am using page-object gem with ruby in the cucumber framework.
The HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="tab-pane fadeIn animated active" id="ssl-settings-client">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="panel-group" id="profiles">
    <div class="with-2-cols-md">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading heading-clickable" data-target="#profile-111" data-toggle="collapse">
        <div class="pull-right">
         <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm mtn5 mrn10">
          <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-default" href="/customers/388/edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a>
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="/customers/initialize_new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span></a>
          <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" title="Delete" class="btn btn-default" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/customers/388"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
         </div>
         <div class="collapsed accordion-icon profile-name" data-target="#profile-388" data-toggle="collapse">
          automated_front_end
         </div>
```

I tried to use the following code:
div = div_element(:text => 'automated_front_end').text

How would you go about it?
thx

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to get - ie what is the output you need? It would also help to show all of the related code (eg page object) and the errors/unexpected results that occurred.

Comment: @JustinKo thanks for your reply. the output i want to get it is the text of the the profile which is "automated_front_end". i'm not getting errors per se but it is printing a black row instead.